# Add a new category in a sharepoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, library

I want to add a new category as below in my library[image] but I can not do it. Can not find how to do it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want add grouping in List/Library view or you want add another category Similar to `product family`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add new "Product family" category - try to open List settings(gear in the upper right corner -> List settings) then click on column named "Product family" in columns section and look what the type of the column.

If type is Choice

- Click on this column and add new category

If type is Lookup

- Click on this column and look what is the name of lookup list
- Click on Site contents(gear in the upper right corner -> Site contents)
- Open lookup list
- Add new item in this list

If type is Single line of text

- Just add new item in your list and fill new category in the field "Product family"

Comment: Thx a lot for your help Raf !

Answer (score -1):

It seems that this is Group By feature in the view settings.

Go to library settings->click the relevant view name under Views section->scroll down the Group By section->select the relevant column name.